# jquery .on() not binding to new elements from jquerymobile changePage

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have 2 pages that use the same template. The only thing different is the `data-role="content"` is different.  I am using `$.mobile.changePage('page2.php');` but the `all.js` file that I have in my head is not binding to the elements loaded in `page2`.

The script tag for 'all.js' is in the head of both pages and from what I have read, only the `data-role="page"` is loaded from the second page. Which is fine because the `.on()` bind should be binding to the new elements, however it isn't. If I specifically refresh `page2.php` then the `all.js` file works, however if I use `changePage` it will not.

Why aren't the new elements pulled in from `changePage` binding to `all.js` `.on()` selector?

HTML for both pages

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">

    <title>Title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile.theme-1.2.0.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.min.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pages/all.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" data-theme="d">
    <div data-id="head" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <h1>Name</h1>
        <a href="#" id="headingsActionButton" class="ui-btn-right headingsActionButton hidden" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="check">Save</a>

    </div>

    <div id="mainContent" data-role="content">
        {PageContent}
    </div>
    <div align="center" data-id="foot" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-inset="false" data-theme="c">
        Powered by 
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

all.js

```
$(function() {
    /**
     * Prevent the header and footer from hiding on a non element tap.
     */
    $("[data-role=header], [data-role=footer]").fixedtoolbar({ tapToggle: false });

    /**
     * Scroll to the top of the collapsible heading
     */
    $('.ui-collapsible-heading').on('click', function(e) {
        window.scrollTo(0, $(this).offset().top - $('[data-role=header]').height());
        $('.headingsActionButton').addClass('hidden');
        var attr = $(this).parent().attr('data-action-id');
        if (typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false) {
            if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('ui-collapsible-collapsed')) {
                console.log('expanded');
                $('.headingsActionButton').attr('data-action-id', $(this).parent().attr('data-action-id'));
                $('.headingsActionButton .ui-btn-text').text($(this).parent().attr('data-action-text'));
                $('.headingsActionButton').toggleClass('hidden');
            } else {
                console.log('collapsed');
            }
        }
    });


});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.on` is not a simple drop in to replace `.live`, you need to use the correct syntax.

```
$(context).on(events,targetelements,eventhandler)
```

For example,

```
$('#someparentelement').on('click','.ui-collapsible-heading',function(){...});
```

To directly match what `.live` was doing, use `document` in place of `'#someparentelement'`

**Update**

The root of the problem is the click event on .ui-collapsible-heading is being stopped by JQM, meaning it can't bubble up to the document. That leaves the only way to handle the event is binding it directly on that element without delegation.

With that in mind, you'll need it to run on every page, so you need to remove `$(function(){})` since it only runs on the first page and instead use `$(document).on("pageinit",function(){})`

Comment: I tried this as `$(document).on('click', '.ui-collapsible-heading')` and that didn't work.

Comment: Also note this works if I manually refresh the page after a changePage.

Comment: Oh, also, remove `$(function() {`, it isn't a good idea to use document ready in jQuery mobile since it only gets called on the first page. I'm not sure what that means for your fixedToolbar code.

Comment: I also tried `$('.mfe_collapsibles').on('click', '.ui-collapsible-heading', function(e) {` with `.mfe_collapsibles` being a grandparent div and that didn't work.

Comment: The code in question will work without document ready if binding from the document.

Comment: If document ready is required for it to work, then it won't work for pages after the first page since document ready will not be triggered for those pages.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18121/discussion-between-bot-and-kevin-b)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.ui-collapsible-heading').live('click', function(e) { ... });
```

'Live' works like 'on', but set the event to new elements.